# Append HTML with JS. MVC c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I add fields dynamically in my View. It's working good, but rules and events don't work for the new field. How do I can apply rules for new fields, like when you load the page for the first time.
If I added a new record in the database and refreshed the page, when rules and validation are working.

```
$(function addIstPIR() {
        var i = @Model.pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya.Count-1;
        $('.addIstPIR').click(function () {
            i++;
            var html2Add = "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-6 form-material floating padding-horizontal-3 '>" +
                                "<select class='form-control' data-val='true' data-val-required='This field is required * !.' id='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya_" + i + "__pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya' name='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya[" + i + "].pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya'>" +
                                    "<option selected='selected'></option>" +
                                    "<option value='1'>Select 1</option>" +
                                    "<option value='2'>Select 2</option>" +
                                    "<option value='5'>Select 3</option>" +
                                    "<option value='6'>Select 4</option>" + 
                                "</select>" +
                                "<label class='floating-label text-truncate' for='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya_" + i + "__pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya'>Some text</label>" +
                                "<span class='text-danger field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya[" + i + "].pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='form-material floating'>" +
                                "<input id='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya_" + i + "__ppt3041id' name='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya[" + i + "].ppt3041id' value='0' type='hidden'/>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5  form-material floating'>" +
                               "<input class='form-control tDecimal3' data-val='true' data-val-number='The field Some text must be a number' data-val-required='Some text.' id='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya_" + i + "__pt3041ivolume' name='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya[" + i + "].pt3041ivolume' value='' type='text'>" +
                               "<label class='floating-label text-truncate' for='pt3041iResourseBlockedSnyatyZamechaniya_" + i + "__pt3041ivolume'>Some Text</label>" +
                             "</div>";
            $('#IFPIRBlock').append(html2Add);
        })
    })
```

Comment: Have a look at the `on()` function. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/12/Replacing-jQuerylive-with-jQueryon

Comment: Iam trying use  $(document).on('click', '.addIstPIR', function () {, but it didn't work

Comment: See this fiddle to demonstrate it. https://jsfiddle.net/kr75yutb/

Comment: i have problem with this "data-val-number=" and same boostrap. Customs validation don't work for new field. Anyway thanks.